# Ext JS 3.0.0 - Using Ext.LiveGrid cannot load data to grid from data store

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using livegrid to view all data from server data store, but the problem is data store can load (I am using Firebug and check console tab) but in my live grid cannot view all data from load data store and saying **'No data to display'** at status bar, please help me to solve this.

I am using Ext JS 3.0.0 and adding Ext.ux.Livegrid to my application.

this is code of my live grid configuration :

```
        var myView = new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.GridView({
            nearLimit: 100,
            loadMask: {
                msg: 'Buffering. Please wait...'
            }
        });

        var livegrid = new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.GridPanel({
            enableDragDrop: false,
            cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
            new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel(),
            new SharpJs.RowNumberer()
            , { header: 'Nama Kegiatan', dataIndex: 'RCSA_NAME', sortable: true, allowBlank: false }
            , { header: 'Unit', dataIndex: 'AUDITEE_NAME', sortable: true, allowBlank: false }
            , { header: 'Risk Owner', dataIndex: 'NAMA_RISKOWNER', sortable: true, allowBlank: false }
            , { header: 'Kode Kegiatan', dataIndex: 'RCSA_CODE', sortable: true, allowBlank: false, maxLength: 100 }
            , { header: 'Periode', dataIndex: 'RISK_PERIOD_NAME', sortable: true, allowBlank: true }
            , { header: 'SMART', dataIndex: 'Id', renderer: smartRenderer }
            , { header: 'Kajian Risiko', dataIndex: 'Id', renderer: kajRisiko }
            , { header: 'Kesimpulan', dataIndex: 'Id', renderer: sumRenderer }
            , { header: 'Pengesahan', dataIndex: 'LEGITIMATION_NO', renderer: pengRenderer }
            , { header: 'Verifikasi', dataIndex: 'VERIFICATION_NO', renderer: verRenderer }
            , { header: 'Mentor', dataIndex: 'AUDITEE_EMPLOYEE_NAME', renderer: coachRenderer }
            , { header: 'Rollback', dataIndex: 'Id', renderer: rollRenderer }
            , { header: 'Jenis Anggaran', dataIndex: 'TBL_PAR_BUDGET_TYPE_NAME', sortable: true, allowBlank: false }
            , { header: 'Anggaran', dataIndex: 'ANGGARAN', sortable: true, allowBlank: false, renderer: Ext.util.Format.indMoney }
        , { header: 'Verifikasi', dataIndex: 'VERIFIKASI', sortable: true, allowBlank: true }
        , { header: 'Tanggal Pembuatan', dataIndex: 'RCSA_SESSION_DATE', sortable: true, allowBlank: true, renderer: SharpJs.dateRenderer }
            , { header: 'Created Date', dataIndex: 'CREATED_DATE', sortable: true, renderer: SharpJs.dateRenderer }
            , { header: 'Created By', dataIndex: 'CREATED_BY', sortable: true }
            , { header: 'Modified Date', dataIndex: 'MODIFIED_DATE', sortable: true, renderer: SharpJs.dateRenderer }
            , { header: 'Modified By', dataIndex: 'MODIFIED_BY', sortable: true }
        ]),
            loadMask: {
                msg: 'Loading...'
            },
            title: 'Daftar Kajian Kegiatan Proyek',
            height: SharpJs.FormHeight,
            width: SharpJs.FormWidth,
            stripeRows: true,
            store: new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.Store({
                autoLoad: true,
                url: SharpJs.RootUrl + "TblProjRcsas",
                bufferSize: 300,
                reader: new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.JsonReader({
                    root: 'resultset',
                    versionProperty: 'version',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount',
                    fields: [
        'Id'
        , 'AUDITEE'
        , 'AUDITEE_ID'
        , 'AUDITEE_NAME'
        , 'TBL_PAR_PROJ_RISK_PERIOD'
        , 'RISK_PERIOD_ID'
        , 'RISK_PERIOD_NAME'
        , 'RCSA_CODE'
        , 'RCSA_NAME'
        , 'START_DATE'
        , 'END_DATE'
        , 'CREATED_DATE'
        , 'CREATED_BY'
        , 'MODIFIED_DATE'
        , 'MODIFIED_BY'
        , 'ANGGARAN'
        , 'VERIFIKASI'
        , 'TBL_PAR_BUDGET_TYPE_ID'
        , 'TBL_PAR_BUDGET_TYPE_NAME'
        , 'RCSA_SESSION_DATE'
        , 'RCSA_SESSION_TIME'
        , 'RCSA_SESSION_LOCATION'
        , 'VERIFICATION_NO'
        , 'VERIFICATION_DATE'
        , 'VERIFICATION_OWNER'
        , 'LEGITIMATION_NO'
        , 'LEGITIMATION_DATE'
        , 'LEGITIMATION_OWNER'
        , 'AUDITEE_RISKOWNER_ID'
        , 'NAMA_RISKOWNER'
        , 'SURAT_RISKOWNER'
        , 'LEGITIMATION_EXA_STATUS'
        , 'LEGITIMATION_APPROVE_STATUS'
        , 'VERIFICATION_MRF_STATUS'
        , 'VERIFICATION_MRO_STATUS'
        , 'VERIFICATION_KSMR_STATUS'
        , 'AUDITEE_EMPLOYEE_AUDITEE_ID'
        , 'AUDITEE_EMPLOYEE_ID'
        , 'AUDITEE_EMPLOYEE_NAME'
        ],
}),
                    sortInfo: { field: 'Id', direction: 'ASC' },
                    baseParams: {skip:0, take:15}
                }),
            selModel: new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.RowSelectionModel(),
            view: myView,
            bbar: new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.Toolbar({
                    view: myView,
                    displayInfo: true
                })
            });

            livegrid.render('DataGrid');
```

and this is my live grid with no data to display:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qtAd.jpg

thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

Your JsonReader root property is set to be resultset, however, I don't see where you add this to your returned json.

Your json construct that gets returned should follow the rules of the root parameter: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonReader-cfg-root

and should include the element specified. 
Example:

```
{resultset:[{unit:"1"},{unit:"2"}]};
```

If the root element is missing, the store doesn't know what to read the array from.

Comment: I think that's no problem with store, because, the store is already loaded, and all data is "Read". The problem is with store is already loaded, how a livegrid can read all data from store? there I miss something?

Comment: I know that this must match. Can you edit the post with a sample of the json that gets returned?